# Shopping Cart emptying after 15 items

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i have a serious problem with the cart.
If I add in the cart 14 products, everything is ok, but if I add another products, the cart is cleared.
When i have 15 products in cart, this is cleared and i see the message "There are no products in your cart".

Joomla! 1.0.15. I have found solution in here http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=105960.0 but seems there is old joomla version installed and I do not have option set session handler or "update tables if necessary"
How can I resolve?
Thanks

Comment: have you got the latest version of Joomla and VirtueMart?

Comment: this is life client website with a lot modules user information etc. Wonder if there is simple fix

Comment: well it's not normal for for the cart to be cleared when you add 15 products so make sure to have the latest version of VirtueMart installed first

Comment: actually it is not only mine issue and problem is in Joomla

Comment: if it's a Joomla related problem then you should be reporting it to the official Joomla site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the server problem just moved to another hosting